# SQL - Recursive statement

Tags: sql

i've got a problem with this recursive statement. the table is the following

id1, id2, level

for each id1,id2 i need to find all possible couple with the correct level.
for example

```
- t1 t2 level 1
- t1 t3 - level 2 (id1 - id2 level 1 + id2-id3 level 1)
```

of course is necessary also that if there is not relationship between id1 and id2 i must signal it with "0".

i tried with a CTE but it didn't work well? Someone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try a recursive CTE?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Put some test data with expected output

Comment: well consider the relationship id1=001 and id2=002 it is a directly relationship so level 1. if id1=001 have also a relationship with id3=003 with a level of 1, exist also a relationship between id1 and id3 of 2 (1+1) because id1 and id3 have in common id2.

Comment: i hope that the comment clarify what i'm trying to do.

Comment: I'm confused. How about you give us some example data and what the expected output might look like. Then we can help you connect the dots. You can use http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html to help format a table that will look readable here. Also, add the example table and expected output to your quesion, not as a comment.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? And please add the attempts you already did.